# Invalid conversion specifier '2'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata, ios6

i am trying to build my app in iOS 6 and for iphone 5. I am using gdata-objectivec-client-1.10.0 in my app but when i build my app then it does it is giving this error in the GDataDateTime.m file. 
Can any one please help me in solving this issue.

```
 timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"T%02ld:%02ld:%0l2d%@",
```

**ERROR is "invalid conversation from specifier 2"**

[image]

now it is giving this error after swapping the "l" and "2". any help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was, i am using old GData sdk. I just change the compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2 from Apple LLVM 4.1 and it compiles app perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

the last one is not `%02ld` the letter "l" and the "2" are swapped.

edit: 
instead of:

```
timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"T%02ld:%02ld:%0l2d%@",
```

write:

```
timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"T%02ld:%02ld:%02ld%@",
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand. what should i do to fix this.

Comment: I downvoted before the edit because it didn't make any sense. Removed now :) . Didn't have time to comment before the edit, sorry.

Comment: Sorry guys, only had one coffee this morning. Producing understandable language is still difficult..

Comment: hey guy will you please guide me about 2nd problem. I donot know why it is not giving errors, i am using the same code for ios5 and it is working. but not for ios 6

Comment: It means whatever is inside the macro is causing the problem. Add the macro expansion and we might be able to help.

Comment: lets try;) Select the Macro and do a `Find for Text selected text in Workspace`. You probably will find it defined in GDataObject.h. The macro will check that the service you are requesting is available. I belief google only uses services with version 2 and higher anyway. So unless you really need to have present the actual check inside your code, you might want to consider commenting the two lines that give you the error.

Comment: i donot know what is the problem when i comment it keeps giving errors

Comment: now it is giving error on  [dummyStream_ setDelegate:self];
error is GDataGatherInputStream *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSSTreamDelegate>'